# Logback stopped working when upgraded spring-core maven dependency to 5.3.27

Tags: spring, logback

I was using spring core maven dependency 4.2.4 and the same for spring context, now I've upgraded both of them to 5.3.27 and my logback maven dependency is still on 1.1.11, now upgrading the dependencies I was successfully able to make the build but as soon I run the build following error message comes:-

```
21:15:26,467 |-ERROR in 
c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Filename pattern 
[/Users/a13215586/Documents/WORK/AirtelTv/codebase/logs/tv/play/error/%d{yyyy-MM-dd, 
aux}/play-error.MAC-a13215586.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.%i.log.gz] contains an integer token 
converter, i.e. %i, INCOMPATIBLE with this configuration. Remove it.
```

Along with the following warnings followed by the above errors:-

```
21:15:26,467 |-WARN in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@873827336 - 
Subcomponent did not start. TimeBasedRollingPolicy will not start.
21:15:26,468 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[ERRORLOG] - 
TriggeringPolicy has not started. RollingFileAppender will not start
```

my logback.xml is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false" scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
<timestamp key="_timestamp" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>

<appender name="ERRORLOG"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder class="in.wynk.lib.analytics.LogstashEventEncoder"/>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/Users/a13215586/Documents/WORK/AirtelTv/codebase/logs/tv/play/error/%d{yyyy-MM-dd, aux}/play-error.${hostname}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.%i.log.gz
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>180</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<appender name="ASYNC_ERRORLOG" queueSize="10000"
          class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="ERRORLOG"/>
    <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%level %date [%thread] [%X{rid}] [%X{uid}] [%file:%line] %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/Users/a13215586/Documents/WORK/AirtelTv/codebase/logs/tv/play/app/%d{yyyy-MM-dd, aux}/play.${hostname}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.%i.log.gz
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>240</maxHistory>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>1GB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<appender name="ASYNC_FILE" queueSize="10000"
          class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
</appender>


<!-- logstashLogs -->
<appender name="ANALYTIC_LOG_FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/Users/a13215586/Documents/WORK/AirtelTv/codebase/logs/tv/play/logstash/%d{yyyy-MM-dd, aux}/play-logstashLogs.${hostname}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.%i.log.gz
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>180</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<!-- transactionLogs-->
<appender name="TRANSACTION_LOG_FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/Users/a13215586/Documents/WORK/AirtelTv/codebase/logs/tv/play/logstash/%d{yyyy-MM-dd, aux}/play-transactionLogs.${hostname}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.%i.log.gz
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>180</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNC_ANALYTIC_LOG_FILE" queueSize="10000"
          class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="ANALYTIC_LOG_FILE"/>
    <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
</appender>


<appender name="ASYNC_TRANSACTION_LOG_FILE" queueSize="10000"
          class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="TRANSACTION_LOG_FILE"/>
    <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
</appender>


<logger name="playback" additivity="false" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_ANALYTIC_LOG_FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="editorJiPlayback" additivity="false" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_ANALYTIC_LOG_FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="cpplayback" additivity="false" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_ANALYTIC_LOG_FILE"/>
</logger>


<!-- end of logstashLogs -->

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_ERRORLOG"/>
</root>
```

What should I try to eradicate this issue?